# Variance of $\operatorname{tr}(W^2)$ with $W \sim \text{Wishart}(n, \Sigma)$

Tags: distributions, variance, expected-value, wishart-distribution

Suppose $W \sim \text{Wishart}(n, \Sigma)$, where $\Sigma \in \mathbb R^{p\times p}$, the expectation of $\operatorname{tr}(W^2)$ is
$$E[\operatorname{tr}(W^2)] =n(n+1)\operatorname{tr}(\Sigma^2) + n\operatorname{tr}^2(\Sigma).$$
Is there any reference or conclusion for
$$\operatorname{Var}[\operatorname{tr}(W^2)]~~\text{or}~~E[\operatorname{tr}^2(W^2)]~~?$$

Comment: Should the last expression be $E[tr(W^2)]$ ?

Comment: Yep @RobertLong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is printed below.
$$E[\text{tr}^2(W^2)] = (8n^3 + 20n^2+20n)\text{tr}(\Sigma^4) + (16n^2 + 16n)\text{tr}(\Sigma^3)\text{tr}(\Sigma) + (n^4 + 2n^3 + 5n^2 + 4n)\text{tr}^2(\Sigma^2) + (2n^3 + 2n^2  + 8n)\text{tr}(\Sigma^2)\text{tr}^2(\Sigma) + n^2\text{tr}^4(\Sigma).$$